# Could not load file or assembly 'IKVM.OpenJDK.Security, Version=8.1.5717.0

Tags: saxon, ikvm

After upgration from Saxon API Version(9.7.0.6) to 10.5.1.0
we get below issue on code sample line:
Could not load file or assembly 'IKVM.OpenJDK.Security, Version=8.1.5717.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Code  Sample:
_healthCheckServiceHost = new WebServiceHost(new NancyWcfGenericService(),
new Uri(httpEndPoint));

Comment: @MartinHonnen Please guide here

Comment: Is that sample line of code using any Saxon APIs at all? How exactly did you upgrade, did you install the NuGet package of Saxon HE 10.5.1? Does your code use any other IKVM based, C# to Java APIs than Saxon HE? Can you post a stack trace?

Comment: Please insert any details by editing your question and showing well formatted lines, don't dump all of that into comments.

Comment: at Nancy.Hosting.Wcf.NancyWcfGenericService..ctor(INancyBootstrapper bootstrapper)
   at Diagnostics.RuleEngine.WindowsService.BootstrapService.StartHealthCheckMonitor() 
   in C:\..\Diagnostics.RuleEngine.WindowsService\BootstrapService.cs:line 94
   healthCheckServiceHost.Close();
            if (serviceHost != null)
        //Line94    {
                serviceHost.Close();
                serviceHost = null;
            }

Comment: at Diagnostics.RuleEngine.WindowsService.BootstrapService.Start() 
in C:\..\BootstrapService.cs:line 43
//////Line Number 43: StartHealthCheckMonitor();

Comment: if (serviceHost != null) {                serviceHost.Close();           }
            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(BootstrapService));
            serviceHost.Open();

            string httpEndPoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HttpEndPoint"];
            _healthCheckServiceHost = new WebServiceHost(new NancyWcfGenericService(),
                new Uri(httpEndPoint));
            _healthCheckServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(NancyWcfGenericService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
            _healthCheckServiceHost.Open();  @MartinHonnen Please guide here

Answer (score 1):

"IKVM.OpenJDK.Charsets.dll" not load in debug folder. So I have added manually then It working fine. Thanks @MichaelKay and @MartinHonnen.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little strange that none of your code samples have any obvious relationship to Saxon.

It's always difficult to advise on configuration/installation issues, because there's such a wide variety of things you can do to make it fail, but the first thing we need is exact details of how you installed the product, and configuration details of your platform.

Answer (score 0):

```
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetDeclaringType(RuntimeType type)
```

at System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.GetEnclosingType()
at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.b__14(Type type)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext() at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.AutoRegisterInternal(IEnumerable`1 assemblies, DuplicateImplementationActions duplicateAction, Func`2 registrationPredicate) at Nancy.DefaultNancyBootstrapper.AutoRegister(TinyIoCContainer container, IEnumerable`1 ignoredAssemblies)
at Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperBase`1.Initialise()
at Nancy.Hosting.Wcf.NancyWcfGenericService..ctor(INancyBootstrapper bootstrapper)
at Diagnostics.RuleEngine.WindowsService.BootstrapService.StartHealthCheckMonitor()
in C:..\Diagnostics.RuleEngine.WindowsService\BootstrapService.cs:line 94
at Diagnostics.RuleEngine.WindowsService.BootstrapService.Start() in C:..\Diagnostics.RuleEngine.WindowsService\BootstrapService.cs:line 43
at Diagnostics.RuleEngine.WindowsService.Program.<>c.b__0_2(BootstrapService tc) in C:..\Diagnostics.RuleEngine.WindowsService\Program.cs:line 37

Comment: @Michael Kay Before upgradation project working properly. You can check stackTrace in below Answer. Sorry but it very urgent, please guide.

Comment: @MichaelKay "IKVM.OpenJDK" available in "Saxon-HE.10.5.1\lib\net35" package folder.

Comment: StackOverflow is not an official support channel, it's a way of getting help from other members of the community. If you need urgent support and you have a support contract with Saxonica, you should use the Saxonica support tracker. (It remains true that however urgent the problem is, we will need the right information to help us solve it.)